# Solve transcendental equation for different values and enter in vector

Tags: list-manipulation

Hello I want to solve the equation for the x values, y == x + 1/4*(x^2*(2 - x - 7*x^5 + 6*x^6))/(x - 1)^2  for values of y in the interval 0 and 30 in steps of 0.01. Making two vectors, one for x and one for y values would be really helpful. Does anyone know how to do this?

If I can get Mathematica to spit them out I can throw them into python and do the rest of what I need to do.

Comment: `Making two vectors, one for x and one for y values` Which `x` value? You do know this polynomial has more than one root?  So which one you want?

Comment: Ah sorry, I want the one root that is real and positive.

Answer (score 2):

One way might be to use a `Table`

```
sol[y_] := (z := 
    Select[x /. 
      NSolve[y == x + 1/4*(x^2*(2 - x - 7*x^5 + 6*x^6))/(x - 1)^2, 
       x], (Internal`RealValuedNumericQ[#] && # > 0 &)]; 
   If[z != {}, z[[1]]]);

data = Table[{sol[y], y}, {y, 0, 30, .01}];
Grid[data, Frame -> All]
```

For example, using step of `1` instead of `0.01` the output is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Some values of `y` do not produce a root which is real and positive. May be you can put a `Nothing`  in there?

Comment: the data table actually looks really good! Thank you! One last question... is there anyway to make it print these x values as maybe a list separated by commas? If not I can maybe figure something out. This has put me a long way forward already!

Comment: @Crush the matrix is there. it is called `data` it has 2 columns. One for `x` and one for `y`.   Notice that when there is no root which meets criteria, there is a `Null` in its place. You decide what to put there in this case. just type `data` to see the data. To show just the `x` values type `data[[All, 1]]`

Comment: Oh excellent! Thanks for the data[[All,1]] tip. That is exactly what I needed! I was just typing data and then messing with the ways to show the values. That is just perfect! Thank you so much. I'll be using these types of commands so much these next few weeks... It's been a huge help!!

Comment: @Crush you are welcome. it was no problem. `Table` is very useful command to learn in Mathematica.